# What am I doing wrong with my AI?

Tags: lua, artificial-intelligence

I've been programming an AI with Lua that you communicate with it in my own logical language. I stumbled across a problem and I can't seem to figure this out.

I'm trying to put y/n questions in. I pretty much said: mi=David la; (sets variable to David. la; is punctuation) la mi=David dor la; (Is 'mi' equal to 'David'?)

When I typed that into it, 'ROBO-DUDE' didn't say anything.

```
if v == "lol" then
  local yes = true
  for _,v in pairs(mode[2]) do
    if v == false then
      print(v)
      yes = false
    end
    print(yes)
  end
  print(yes)
  if yes == true then
    things = things .. "jar; "
  else
    things = things .. "awa; "
  end
end
```

This block of code is in a loop for the 'la' statement. 'dor' means to respond yes/no, the lexer changes it to 'lol'.

When I tested it, the code seemed to skip the dor/lol part of the loop. I went to check the lexer.

```
if v == "dor" then
  sentence[#sentence+1] = "lol"
end
```

I have no clue what went wrong here. I would like somebody's help on this problem.

Comment: This is barely AI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I found the problem. When I used a for loop, I used the variable 'v' for the main parser loop **and** the one that looped through another table/array. I believe changing the variable (any of them) will fix my issue.